# Bukkit toggling a scoreboard

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to toggle a scoreboard in bukkit by using a command '/sb toggle'. However I can't seem to make it work because the compiler keeps looping through the code. So if I remove a key from the ArrayList, the compiler will continue it's executing which isn't what I want.

```
// Creating the ArrayList to store the data.

ArrayList<UUID> toggle = new ArrayList<>();

// Checking if it contains the player's UUID.

    if (toggle.contains(p.getUniqueId())) {

// Removing the UUID from the ArrayList to turn the scoreboard off.
        toggle.remove(p.getUniqueId());
        p.setScoreboard(Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard());
        p.sendMessage(Main.msg + ChatColor.RED + "Scoreboard turned off.");
    } else {
// Adding the UUID again to the ArrayList so that we it can turn on.
        toggle.add(p.getUniqueId());
        SideScoreboard.getInstance().setScoreboardPlayer(p);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Scoreboard turned on.");
    }
```

So the problem is that it keeps telling me that the Scoreboard is turned on. When it really should just toggle between off and on each time I execute the command.

Comment: Is this all in one method? If so then `toggle` will be empty every time you hit the `if` so the condition is always false.

Comment: @Kirill it is, should I make the ArrayList global?

Comment: Yes, that way it will keep its contents between calls to this method.

Comment: @Kirill Thanks! Could you explain why this is, because I read about the difference between global and local variables. And if I'm not mistaken then you should always use local unless multiple methods need to use the variable.

Comment: I've gone into the 'why' in my answer, but as for that advice, note that 'multiple methods' should include 'multiple *calls to the same* method'. If your method needs to keep some value persisted even after it returns, it should be in a broader scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this method is called, every line within it will run, one by one.

Look at your first line,

```
ArrayList<UUID> toggle = new ArrayList<>();
```

Every time the method runs, a new, *empty* `ArrayList` is created and assigned to `toggle`. More so than the scope of the variable, this is the root of the problem.

Once the `if` statement is reached,

```
if (toggle.contains(p.getUniqueId()))
```

`toggle` will still refer to the empty `ArrayList` that was just assigned to it. It does not contain anything, so it certainly won't contain `p.getUniqueId()`.

The fix here is to give `toggle` a broader scope than the method, and not reassign it each time this method runs. This might look like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private ArrayList<UUID> toggle = new ArrayList<>();

    public void toggleScoreboard(Player p){
        if (toggle.contains(p.getUniqueId()))
        // Rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Then every time the method runs, it refer to the same `ArrayList`, which will persist the values stored in it.